# How to make wowza generate random ts file name in HLS stream

Tags: wowza, http-live-streaming

Now I get the m3u8 contents like this

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:797
#EXTINF:2.0,
media-u2w5gbqf0_b2625536_797.ts
#EXTINF:2.0,
media-u2w5gbqf0_b2625536_798.ts
#EXTINF:2.0,
media-u2w5gbqf0_b2625536_799.ts
#EXTINF:2.0,
media-u2w5gbqf0_b2625536_800.ts
#EXTINF:2.0,
media-u2w5gbqf0_b2625536_801.ts
```

what I want to get is like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:797
#EXTINF:2.0,
media-LAJ123FMK.ts
#EXTINF:2.0,
media-KOAKS23W2.ts
#EXTINF:2.0,
media-JLASFK234.ts
#EXTINF:2.0,
media-SLFJAQ23D.ts
#EXTINF:2.0,
media-ALSF1234L.ts
```

Is this possible by any plugin in wowza, or doing this by some wowza server API?

Comment: What is the purpose?

Comment: @JohnnyV For example make the client can't retrieve the ts file that is before the current time(ts files are upload to S3 server realtime).

Comment: Players won't attempt to load segments unless they are referenced in the playlist.  They won't assume incremental numbers or anything.  What you have to guarantee is that the files are uploaded before the playlist is updated.

Comment: Players won't do that. But someone can do that. when someone get the playlist, he can then guess the former ts file name to see the previous live content which is not we want.

Comment: If a user grabs the manifest for a VOD then all the segments will be listed in the playlist; every single one.  If a user grabs the manifest of a LIVE stream then only the segment window will be listed.  Any segments after the window do not exist yet.  If you cannot hide the contents of the manifest then you cannot prevent fast-loading of streams.  If you could temporally control access to segments then you would break seeking from within the player because seeking would appear as fast-loading.  The only thing you can do is apply rate limits so make fast-loading slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can custom the ID of your chunks in Wowza by creating a class that implements the **IHTTPStreamerCupertinoLiveStreamPacketizerChunkIdHandler** but the id must be a number (long), not letters.

```
 long   onAssignChunkId(com.wowza.wms.httpstreamer.cupertinostreaming.livestreampacketizer.HTTPStreamerCupertinoLiveStreamPacketizerChunkIdContext chunkIdContext)
```